# How can I disable zoom reset on activating next char in XCOM?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

In X-COM Unknown Enemy I love to zoom out to maximum for getting a good overview while moving soldiers, attacking enemies and thinking about my next moves.

As we all know the game automatically advances to the next soldier if you have spent all movement points of one. But everytime that happens, the game also automatically zooms in to default zoom level. How can I disable that, so that the zoom stays always the same (maximized)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mod recommended by Falem is not compatible with the latest XCOM version and is also no longer maintained. Instead you can use [XCOM Camera Tweaks](http://www.nexusmods.com/xcom/mods/444/?), in particular the *Camera Zoom Levels for EU and EW* script. Although this does not prevent the reset of zoom levels when selecting another soldier, it enables you to set a default zoom level in the script.

After loading `CameraZoom-EU-EW.txt` into [XCOM UPK Patcher](http://www.nexusmods.com/xcom/mods/448/?), set the number to your desired value, for example `2500` (which is really far away):

```
// Change 1884.0 to whatever value you like (vanilla value is 1256.0)
ALIAS=DefaultDistance:<%f2500.0>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using the following mod it has a lot of features that can help you out.

[XCOM ToolBoks](http://xcom.nexusmods.com/mods/79/?)

One of the features of the mod is to disable auto zoom and the description is as following.

**Disable Auto Zoom** - By default, the game zooms in/out when you switch soldiers (tab/shift/mouse4/mouse5), which can be disabled by selecting this option. Although, other events will still trigger the camera to zoom in.

Note, there is a bug when starting/loading a mission that locks the camera in place when Auto Zoom is disabled. To unlock it, just click on an unselected soldier with the mouse or enter Free Aiming mode by selecting a Grenade or Rocket Launcher etc.

Comment: Late reply, but I could not play the game for some time. I tried it out, but the mod is no longer compatible with the game and not maintained. But your answer pointed me into the right direction! I'll add my successful results to your answer and accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @Desty I rejected your edit because I feel that it's far too substantial. Please make that edit into your own answer instead.